How to see Google test output from a remote machine in the test explorer instead of the terminal in VSCode
Currently I am able to run Google-Tests in VSCode and see the results in terminal panel. I want to know how, if at all, can I see those results in the test-explorer?
In my current setup on Ubuntu-20.04, I am using CMake to build the project. Then using a VSCode task I copy the binary over to a remote machine (with WRLinux-Aarch64).
{
            "label": "Copy Binary",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "scp path/to/binary root@10.1.0.1:/usr/data/tests/ut",
            "problemMatcher": []
}

Then using another VSCode task I run the binary in remote machine using GDBServer
{
            "label": "Run Tests",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "ssh root@10.1.0.1 gdbserver :2345 /usr/data/tests/ut/binary --gtest_filter=*"
}

The reason to run it with GDBServer is so that I can debug if the need arises.
There are a few VSCode extensions for Google-Tests out there, but I did not see any supporting running tests remotely.
I searched a lot but could not find anything promising.
If there is a way make this happen, then I would love to know it. Or if there is a VSCode extension for something similar, then please do let me know along with the config settings that I should look into?
